# Audio distortion occurs when using AudioWorkletProcessor with a MediaStream source and connecting a bluetooth device while it is already running

Tags: html5-audio, audio-streaming, web-audio-api

In our project, we use AudioContext to wire up input from a microphone to an AudioWorkletProcessor and out to a MediaStream. Ultimately, this is sent to other peers in a WebRTC call.

If someone loads the page, the audio always sounds fine. But if they connect with a hard-wired microphone like a laptop mic or webcam, then connect a bluetooth device (such as airpods or headphones), then the audio becomes distorted & robotic sounding.

If we tear out all the other code and simplify it, we still have the issue.

bypassProcessor.js

```js
// Basic processor that wires input to output without transforming the data
// https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/web-audio-samples/blob/main/audio-worklet/basic/hello-audio-worklet/bypass-processor.js

class BypassProcessor extends AudioWorkletProcessor {
  process(inputs, outputs) {
    const input = inputs[0];
    const output = outputs[0];

    for (let channel = 0; channel < output.length; ++channel) {
      output[channel].set(input[channel]);
    }

    return true;
  }
}

registerProcessor('bypass-processor', BypassProcessor);
```

main.js

```js
const microphoneStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
  audio: true, // have also tried { channelCount: 1 } and { channelCount: { exact: 1 } }
  video: false
})

const audioCtx = new AudioContext()

const inputNode = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(microphoneStream)

await audioCtx.audioWorklet.addModule('worklet/bypassProcessor.js')
const processorNode = new AudioWorkletNode(audioCtx, 'bypass-processor')

inputNode.connect(processorNode).connect(audioCtx.destination)
```

Interestingly, I have found if you comment out the 2 audio worklet lines and instead create a simple gain node, then it works fine.

```js
// await audioCtx.audioWorklet.addModule('worklet/bypassProcessor.js')
// const processorNode = new AudioWorkletNode(audioCtx, 'bypass-processor')
const gainNode = audioCtx.createGain()
```

Also if you simply create the AudioWorkletNode, but don't even connect it to the others, this also reproduces the issue.

I've created a small React app here that reproduces the problem: https://github.com/JacobMuchow/audio_distortion_repro/tree/master

I've tried some options such as detecting when this happens using 'ondevicechange' event, closing the old AudioContext & nodes and recreating everything, but this only works some of the time. If I wait for some time and then recreate it again, it works so I'm worried about some type of garbage collection issue with the processor when attempting this, but that might be beside the point.

I suspect this has something to do with sample rates... when the AudioContext is correctly recreated it switches from 48 kHz to 16 kHz and then it sounds find. But sometimes it is recreated with 48 kHz still and it continues to sound robotic.

Threads on the internet concerning this are incredibly sparse and I'm hoping someone has specific experience with this issue or this API and can point out what I need to do differently.

Comment: If you're using Chrome, this could be https://crbug.com/1090441 which was recently fixed.  Try using Chrome Canary to see if works better.  There's also a bug about MediaStreams connected to WebAudio.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have done some significant testing with Chrome 92 in Canary and it seems to be working swimmingly now. Feel free to submit this as an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: For posterity, I dug up some other threads through that link as well and felt like this one might be relevant. https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1173656 It looked they solved several issues by fixing a key thing

Comment: I'm really glad this is fixed for you!  I think Firefox was better in this case since Firefox has a pretty implementation of AudioWorklet and MediaStreams too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Chrome, the problem is very likely https://crbug.com/1090441 that was recently fixed.  I think Firefox doesn't have this problem but I didn't check.